# Número de Telefone MYSQL e REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

Preciso selecionar registros que tenham no meio do texto números de telefone para excluir (moderação automática).

É um fórum, pessoas todos os dias comentam e colocam números de telefone no meio do cometário (whats).

Exemplo de formatos: `993345987`, `9 93345987`, `(21)932324343`, `(21)9 3232 4343`, etc...

Se conseguisse pegar dois padrões (`922222222`, `9 2222 2222`) acho que já daria certo.

Estou fazendo assim, bem simples:

```
select * from tabela where comentario REGEXP '[0-9]{9}';
```

Está retornando os números de telefone, porém outros números, como por exemplo `3333333333333333333333`, também retornam registros.

Como limitar para trazer só os números que tenham 9 caracteres somente, assim: `966666666`.

Comment: Uma forma de fazer isso é esta(não está MUITO bem feita mas resolve): (\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[0-9 ]{8,11}|[0-9]{8,11}|[0-9 ]{8,14})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute a query:

```
select * from tabela where comentario REGEXP '.*[0-9]{2}9[0-9]{8}.*|.*[0-9]{2} 9 [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}.*';
```

Veja exemplo prático em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/225b6cf/2

Comment: Se tiver `3393333333333333` (que claramente não é um telefone), sua regex aceita:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfbe36/1

Answer (score 7):

Se são os próprios usuários que colocam os telefones nos comentários, então não há muito controle sobre o formato.

Claro que você pode considerar alguns formatos mais comuns. Pelos seus exemplos, vi que podem ser os 9 dígitos do número do celular, todos juntos ou separados por espaços (`999999999`, `9 9999 9999` ou `99999 9999`), sendo o DDD opcional.

A [resposta do @LipESprY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357752/112052) sugere uma regex bem complexa para contemplar estes (e muitos outros) casos, mas a [sintaxe de regex suportada pelo MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax) infelizmente é [um pouco limitada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html) e não vai suportar todos os recursos propostos, como [`\d` para representar dígitos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) ou os [*lookaheads* e *lookbehinds*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727000) (os trechos que começam com `(?=`, `(?!` e `(?<!`).

Sendo assim, segue uma alternativa que verifica alguns formatos:

```
select * from tabela where comentario REGEXP
'(^|[^0-9])(\\(?0?[0-9]{2}\\)?)?9 ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4}([^0-9]|$)';
```

`(^|[^0-9])`: o `|` [significa **"ou"**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Portanto, este trecho significa "[início da string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)" (`^`) **ou** "qualquer coisa que não seja número" (o `[^` significa que [não quero o que vem depois](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), ou seja, não quero `0-9` - nenhum dígito de zero a 9).

Isso garante que até aqui eu posso estar no início da string (vai que o telefone já está no início), ou tem qualquer caractere que não seja um número (evitando que pegue casos como `3393333333333333333`).

Em seguida temos `(\\(?0?[0-9]{2}\\)?)?`. Vamos por partes, de dentro para fora:

- `0?[0-9]{2}` - um zero opcional (`0?` - o `?` indica "[zero ou uma ocorrência](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)", o que é o mesmo que dizer "opcional"), seguido de 2 dígitos (`[0-9]` é qualquer dígito de 0 a 9, e `{2}` que dizer "[duas ocorrências](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit)"), pois o DDD pode ser escrito como `11` ou `011`
- `\\(?` e `\\)?` - os parênteses podem ser opcionais. Fiz assim porque somente os parênteses `(` e `)` têm significado especial em regex, pois servem para [agrupar sub-expressões](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Por isso temos que escapá-los com `\\`.
- por fim, todo este trecho está entre parênteses (ou seja, agrupado em uma única sub-expressão), e o `?` no final faz todo este trecho ser opcional.

Ou seja, o DDD é opcional.

Depois temos `9 ?`, que é o número 9 seguido de um espaço opcional (repare que há um espaço antes do `?`, ou seja, o espaço que é opcional, não o `9`). Aqui estou assumindo que serão somente números de celular que começam com 9 - lembrando que futuramente poderemos ter celulares que começam com 8, 7, etc, então fica a seu critério deixar sempre `9` ou trocar para `[0-9]` (ou `[7-9]` se quiser que comece somente com 7, 8 ou 9, etc).

Depois temos `[0-9]{4}` (4 dígitos), seguido de um espaço opcional, mais 4 dígitos.

E por fim, temos `([^0-9]|$)`: qualquer caractere que não seja número **ou** o final da string (`$`). Isso também garante que não vai pegar mais dígitos que o necessário, evitando que pegue por exemplo `3393333333333333333`.

[Neste SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a4e837/8) você pode ver esta query funcionando.

---

Se quiser incrementar, pode colocar o separador como hífen ou espaço, por exemplo, assim seriam aceitos números como `9 9123-4567` ou `99123-4567`. Basta trocar os espaços opcionais por `[ \\-]?` (um espaço ou um hífen, opcional). A regex ficaria assim:

```
select * from tabela where comentario REGEXP
'(^|[^0-9])(\\(?0?[0-9]{2}\\)?)?9[ \\-]?[0-9]{4}[ \\-]?[0-9]{4}([^0-9]|$)';
```

[Veja aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85a631/2) ela funcionando.

Também é possível adicionar um espaço opcional depois do DDD:

```
(^|[^0-9])(\\(?0?[0-9]{2}\\)?)? ?9 ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4}([^0-9]|$)
                               ^^
```

Sem esse espaço, o DDD é ignorado para casos como `(11) 9 9123 4567` - somente o número de telefone é capturado pela regex, mas o DDD não, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/Qpi5bL/1). Já colocando o espaço opcional, o DDD também é capturado, [veja aqui a diferença](https://regex101.com/r/Qpi5bL/2).

Outro detalhe é que estamos considerando apenas números de celular. Mas ainda existem números de telefone com 8 dígitos (em residências nem tanto, mas em empresas, ainda é bem comum). Se também quiser considerar estes números, basta colocar o 9 como opcional:

```
(^|[^0-9])(\\(?0?[0-9]{2}\\)?)? ?9? ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4}([^0-9]|$)
                                 ^^
```

---

Só lembrando que, como são os usuários que digitam seus números, sempre poderá haver algum formato estranho que você não previu. E quanto mais possibilidades, mais complexa vai ficando a regex.

Por exemplo, a regex que sugeri só considera um espaço em branco opcional. Mas se quiser que tenha mais de um espaço, pode trocar o `?` por `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), ou limitar a quantidade com chaves (por exemplo, `{0,3}` limita entre 0 a 3 ocorrências).

Há também a possibilidade de um CPF ser confundido com um telefone, já que ambos podem ser escritos sem nenhum separador (`43912341222` pode ser tanto um CPF quanto um DDD + telefone - mesmo que as pessoas costumem escrever o CPF como `439.123.412-22`, quem garante que não vai ter um caso assim? De qualquer forma, veja se isso se aplica aos seus casos). Enfim, regex não é um negócio tão "mágico" assim, e cabe a você avaliar se vai confiar tanto nela ao ponto de remover automaticamente qualquer coisa que ela pegar...

Talvez seja melhor seguir a sugestão dada na [resposta do @LipESprY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357752/112052) e verificar isso **antes** de inserir no banco. Não sei qual linguagem você está usando, mas [a maioria delas possui engines de regex mais modernas](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html), o que permite escrever expressões [como essa](https://regex101.com/r/PN7pJk/1), por exemplo (que usa `\b` para delimitar os telefones, sem precisar usar o "truque" que fiz acima com `(^|[^0-9])` e `([^0-9]|$)`, além de usar `\d` como um atalho para `[0-9]` e `\s` para espaços).

Comment: Excelente complemento! Belo "truque": `(^|[^0-9])` e `([^0-9]|$)`. Realmente, como vc disse, dá pra simplificar bastante a minha expressão, principalmente sobre o `?` para uma ou nenhuma ocorrência. Não tenho costume de usá-lo. kk (LisESprY???)

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- Seu username é muito difícil, tentei digitar só olhando e errei, devia ter feito ctrl-c ctrl-v. Corrigido :-)

Comment: Esquenta não, pow! Tava zuando! kkkk

Answer (score 3):

> "*- [...] que tenham no meio do texto números de telefone para excluir (moderação automática) [...] É um fórum, pessoas todos os dias comentam e colocam números de telefone no meio do cometário*"

Primeiro, vou começar com uma dica. **Moderação automática** sugere que você vai **excluir automaticamente** quando "encontrar alguma ocorrência da expressão regular".

Com uma [simples expressão regular](https://regex101.com/r/rN5DxC/1) você pode acabar excluindo o que não deve ser excluído!

Seguindo essa linha de raciocínio, você deveria criar um sistema de análise: quando a consulta com expressão regular encontrar alguma "suspeita", um humano (moderador) irá avaliar se deve ser excluído ou não. Implemente como achar ideal ao seu uso, claro!

---

O primeiro **requisito** para utilizar expressão regular é entender que elas buscam seguindo um (ou mais) padrão!

Quando se trata de entradas de usuários do seu sistema, você deve prever o máximo possível de padrões para formular sua expressão regular.

E **não apenas *buscar `dois números` seguidos de `um 9` seguido de `oito números` ou este mesmo raciocínio permitindo espaço entre os números***.

Usuários podem escrever um número de telefone sem sequer seguir um padrão... O que podemos fazer é buscar o máximo possível de padrões e, com o tempo, ir evoluindo a expressão regular. Conforme você vai vendo ocorrências que não foram encontradas pela sua consulta...

---

Seguindo esta **minha teoria**, formulei uma expressão que visa encontrar **alguns** dos padrões mais utilizados:

```
(?=\d{2,3}9\d+)(?<!\d)(\d{11,12})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\d{2}\s\d{5}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(0\d{2}\s\d{5}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\d{2}\s9\s\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(0\d{2}\s9\s\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\d{9})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\d\s\d{8})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\(\d{2}\)\d{9})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\(0\d{2}\)\d{9})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\(\d{2}\)\d{1}\s\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\(0\d{2}\)\d{1}\s\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\(\d{2}\)\s\d{1}\s\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\(0\d{2}\)\s\d{1}\s\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)
```

Imensa, né!? Pois bem! Ainda assim ela não encontra nem a metade das inúmeras possibilidades!

Mas tomei como **objetivo principal** os exemplos citados na pergunta e alguns outros que fui pensando conforme ia desenvolvendo a expressão.

[Veja ela funcionando no RegEx101.com/r/ZAfehD/1/](https://regex101.com/r/ZAfehD/1/):

[image: Teste no RegEx101.com]

Repare que, no próprio teste, deixei exatamente a expressão que encontra aquela ocorrência. A expressão como um todo é uma união de todas estas pequenas expressões: `expressão|outra_expressão|outra_expressão|...`.

Agora basta você adicioná-la a sua *query* e, dependendo da quantidade de registros, aguardar algum tempo até retornar as ocorrências...

---

Outra dica é você filtrar **antes de inserir** no banco de dados. Direto na sua aplicação.

Fica muito mais "leve" para o seu servidor executar esta expressão regular em um único texto (comentário) do que percorrer todos os registros na tabela do seu banco de dados...

Ex.: Tentei simular uma consulta no SQLFiddle a fim de complementar esta resposta, mas deu *timeout*...

Comment: Muito bom! Mas tenho quase certeza que dá para simplificar sua regex - [fiz uma](https://regex101.com/r/xfTRqn/4/) que funciona **quase** igual à sua (um caso ou outro fica diferente), e não deve ser difícil mudá-la para ficar igual (fiquei com preguiça de continuar...) Infelizmente, o MySQL não suporta `\d`, nem lookaheads/lookbehinds, mas se seguir sua dica de validar antes de inserir no banco, dá pra usar tranquilo. Sobre o suporte do MySQL, deixei os respectivos links na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357779/112052)